# given <user, movie, rating> how can i use scala to print out the highest rated movie for each user?

Tags: scala, sorting, apache-spark, ubuntu, highest

**input file**

```
(userid,movie,rating)

1,250,3.0

1,20,3.4

1,90,2

2,30,3.5

2,500,2.3

2,20,3.3
```

I am supposed to to get the highest rated movie the user rated. I am completely lost,I had the program running on hadoop but i am brand new to scala. It is comma delimated.

- so far i have gotten here but i cant parse the line because correctly.

  ```
  val inputfile = sc.textFile("/home/input/input.txt") 

  val keyval = inputfile.map(x=>(x(0),x(1)))

  .reduceByKey{case (x, y) => (x._1+y._1, math.max(x._2,y._2))}

  keyval.maxBy { case (key, value) => value }

  keyval.saveAsTextFile("/home/out/word")
  ```
- I get these errors -

  ```
  <console>:26: error: value _1 is not a member of Char

  keyval.reduceByKey{case (x, y) => (x._1+y._1, 
  math.max(x._2,y._2))}
                                      ^
  <console>:26: error: value _1 is not a member of Char
  keyval.reduceByKey{case (x, y) => (x._1+y._1,math.max(x._2,y._2))}
                                           ^
  <console>:26: error: value _2 is not a member of Char
  keyval.reduceByKey{case (x, y) => (x._1+y._1,math.max(x._2,y._2))}
                                                          ^
  <console>:26: error: value _2 is not a member of Char
  keyval.reduceByKey{case (x, y) => (x._1+y._1,math.max(x._2,y._2))}
                                                               ^
  <console>:26: error: value maxBy is not a member of 
  org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Char, Char)]
  keyval.maxBy { case (key, value) => value }
  ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sc.textFile` reads a file line by line as [String] so when you did `inputfile.map(x=>(x(0),x(1)))` the first and the second characters of each line are used as *tuples* . And `reduceByKey` used *the first element of the tuple for grouping* and the second value, a `Char`, is sent inside `reducyByKey` and since the second element is **not** a tuple but simply a `Char`, you can't get elements using `._1` and `._2` and thus you had subsequent errors as

> error: value _1 is not a member of Char

and

> error: value _2 is not a member of Char

And the last error is obvious

> error: value maxBy is not a member of

as you can't perform maxBy on Char elements.

Heres the complete working solution for you

```
val inputfile = sc.textFile("/home/mortaza/input/input.txt")

val keyval = inputfile.map(x=>x.split(",")).map(x => (x(0), (x(1), x(2)))).reduceByKey{case (x, y) => if (x._2 <= y._2) y else x}

keyval.map(x => Seq(x._1, x._2._1, x._2._2).mkString(",")).saveAsTextFile("/home/mortaza/out/wordfreq")
```

which should generate a csv output with following output (the input used is as given in the question)

```
2,30,3.5
1,20,3.4
```

I hope the answer is helpful

Comment: thank you so much! and if i want to just extract the highest rated movie how would i do that? meaning just the second part of the text would show in this example a 30.

Comment: its a `x._2._1` in keyval

Comment: what I am saying for the same example but this time i would like to get the highest rated movie and just the movie to print out. how would i do that?

Comment: Thats what i answered please analyse the short answer and try to understand . Thats the exact answer